# Adding new column from existing data frame to have one row for each Id/Day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I have a dataframe looks like

```
id     TakingTime   TestDesc      TestValue gender
1      28-02-2015   Bilirubin       0.20      2
1      28-02-2015   Cholesterol     169       2
1      28-02-2015   Sodium          129       2
1      28-02-2015   Potassium       3.38      2

1      29-02-2015   Bilirubin       0.20      2
1      29-02-2015   Cholesterol     169       2
1      29-02-2015   Sodium          129       2
1      29-02-2015   Potassium       3.38      2

2      29-02-2015   Bilirubin       0.20      1
2      29-02-2015   Cholesterol     169       1

2      31-02-2015   Sodium          129       1
2      31-02-2015   Potassium       3.38      1
```

and I want to create a new columns for each parameters checked the same day to have only one row for each id with the same taking time like

```
id     TakingTime   Bilirubin      Cholesterol    Sodium    Potassium   gender 
 1    28-02-2015      0.20             169          129         3.38      2
 1    29-02-2015      0.20             169          129         3.38      2
 2    29-02-2015      0.20             169          Nan         Nan       1
 2    31-02-2015      Nan              Nan          129         3.38      1
```

I tried with df.transpose but not really solve because he doesn't regroup all parameters in the same row

Comment: Try `df.pivot(['id', 'gender', 'TakingTime'], 'TestDesc', 'TestValue')`

Comment: I got this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` what's wrong here ?

Comment: I guess your index contains duplicate entries..

Comment: In that case you can try `df.pivot_table(index=['id', 'gender', 'TakingTime'], columns='TestDesc', values='TestValue', aggfunc='first')`

Comment: This time I got `TypeError : pivot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aggfun' ` ...

Can you give me an example of "duplicate entries" ? It's mean exactly same rows of `['id', 'gender', 'TakingTime','TestDesc', 'TestValue']`

Comment: Please use `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`